# How to handle data from one model panel to another in JSF richfaces?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

scenario:  i have a  model  anel  opened  in whci i have a commandlink  which opens another model  to  search  for  data adn  the  data is poplated in a datatable with  a link  in  one of the column. On  click  of the link  i need to  fetch  the row  data an  populate the  value inside the parent  model  panel .

Problem: i am not able to  get  the row  data  form the child  panel  using  `a4j:action`  params and also  the  when the  child panel  is cosed  the parent panel  is also getting closed.

Can any  one please help me solving this issue . i  know this is a  known problem  but if  any  one has a work  around  for it  please let me  know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`<f:setPropertyActionListener>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/setPropertyActionListener.html) in the link in the table. Thus you set the current entity in a managed bean
2. in the modal panel simply output the value of the currently selected item. For example `#{yourBean.current.name}` (you have set `current` on the previous step)
3. The link better be `<a4j:commandLink>` (or button), so that you can `reRender` the modal panel in order to obtain the new data

Comment: @mahesh kumar if so, feel free to mark the answer as accepted (tick below the vote counter)